# Не могу понять, как правильно открыть csv файл в блокноте Jupiter, данные при открытии выводятся в одну строку

Tags: pandas, csv

Для открытия использую следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/cut_data.csv')
print(df.head())
```

Данные выводятся на экран в одну строку, т.е. получаю множество столбцов с заголовками.

Вывод `df.info()` дает следующую информацию:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  
Index: 0 entries  
Columns: 4726 entries, name to Южный административный округ\n  
dtypes: object(4726)  
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes  
None
```

Предполагаю, что проблема в переносе строк '\n', привожу пример части csv файла:

```
name,address,hours,lat,lng,rating,district\nКапитолий,"Москва, Правобережная улица, 1Б","ежедневно, 10:00–22:00",55.880803,37.449824,4.7,Северный административный округ\n
```

Пробовал в текстовом файле оставить пару строк, удалить символ `\n` и разделить строки вручную, с помощью Enter, такой вариант сработал. Но обработать таким способом все данные трудновыполнимо.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что добавить в код при открытии или как исправить csv файл?

Comment: А где у вас в коде выводятся данные? Может вы их выводите неправильно. Проверьте, что выводит `print(df.info())`, например, и добавьте это в вопрос. А так то можете попробовать на всякий в явном виде задать разделители при чтении: `pd.read_csv('/cut_data.csv', sep=',', lineterminator='\n')`, но думаю дело не в этом.

Comment: Вывод df.info() добавил, разделители к сожалению не помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо, конечно, что у вас перенос строки испортился, по-хорошему его нужно бы в исходном `csv` файле исправлять. Но если нет такой возможности, можно попробовать сделать так:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('/cut_data.csv') as file:
    data = file.read()

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data.replace('\\n', '\n')))
```

Параметр `lineterminator` к сожалению не даёт указать разделитель строк длиной больше одного символа, поэтому приходится вот так. Но зато это более универсальное решение, вы можете что угодно с файлом сделать, как угодно его поменять перед загрузкой.